# как при данном числе менять его?

Tags: python

```
coins = 100
print('Ваши коины:',coins)
choice = int(input('1 - магазин, 2 - посмотреть рекламу(+5), 3 - выйти'))

while choice != 3:
  if choice == 1:
    x = int(input('1 - стикер (50), 2 - футболка (100)'))
    if x == 1:
        print('Ваши коины:',coins - 50)
        choice = int(input('1 - магазин, 2 - посмотреть рекламу(+5), 3 - выйти'))
    elif x == 2:
        print('Ваши коины:',coins - 100)
        choice = int(input('1 - магазин, 2 - посмотреть рекламу(+5), 3 - выйти'))
elif choice == 2:
    print('Ваши коины:',coins + 5)  
    choice = int(input('1 - магазин, 2 - посмотреть рекламу(+5), 3 - выйти'))
```

в этом коде я число меняю тип 100 -50 а в следующим действием опять 100 хотя должно быть 50 и как это сделать я не на знаю

Comment: А где вы меняете **переменную** coins?

Answer (score 7):

Вместо

```
print('Ваши коины:',coins - 50)
```

Надо написать

```
coins = coins - 50
print('Ваши коины:',coins)
```

И так - везде.  Это Ваша первая программа? Почитайте главу про "Оператор присваивания".

Comment: спасибо хорошо почитаю,а можете сказать где читать?

Comment: Литературы по питону очень много. Можно начать хотя бы здесь: https://pythonworld.ru/